# Download attachment from outlook via javamail not working

Tags: outlook, jakarta-mail

I am trying to write a program that will download an attachment from outlook automatically through java.

I am using the javamail api. I was able to send the mail using the api but when it comes to downloading the attachment, or even reading mail, I am facing some issue. I have only a basic understanding of the mail protocols that I read up for the purpose of doing this. Other than that, I am not much familiar in that area.

```
public class MailReceiver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getMail();
        sendMail();
    }

    private static void sendMail() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
                String from = "my.email@organization.com";

                String host = "something.organization.com";

                Properties properties = System.getProperties();
                properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

                // Get the default Session object.
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

                try {
                    // Create a default MimeMessage object.
                    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

                    // Set From: header field of the header.
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

                    // Set To: header field of the header.
                    message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                            InternetAddress.parse("some.email@organization.com"));

                    // Set Subject: header field
                    message.setSubject("Test Mail");

                    // Create the message part
                    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                    StringBuilder email = new StringBuilder();
                    email.append("Hello World!");
                    // Fill message
                    messageBodyPart.setContent(email.toString(), "text/html");

                    // Create a multipar message
                    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

                    // Set text message part
                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                    // Send the complete message parts
                    message.setContent(multipart);

                    // Send message
                    Transport.send(message);
                    System.out.println("Mail sent successfully....");
                } catch (MessagingException mex) {
                    mex.printStackTrace();
                }

    }

    private static void getMail() {
        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String user = "my.email@organization.com";
        String password = "my.password";

        String host = "something.organization.com";

        Properties properties = System.getProperties();  
           properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host",host );  
           properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  


           Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,  
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
             return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);  
            }  
           });  



        try {
            Store store = session.getStore("pop3");  
             store.connect(host,user,password);  

             Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox");  
             folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);  

             Message[] message = folder.getMessages(); 

            for (int a = 0; a < message.length; a++) {
                System.out.println("-------------" + (a + 1) + "-----------");
                System.out.println(message[a].getSentDate());

                Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message[a].getContent();

                for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
                    BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                    InputStream stream = bodyPart.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(stream));

                    while (br.ready()) {
                        System.out.println(br.readLine());
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            folder.close(true);
            store.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Since I wasn't sure what I should set inside `session.getStore()` (in `getMail()`), I tried all variations that I could do.

For `pop3` I got the following error:

```
DEBUG POP3: server doesn't support TOP, disabling it
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:174)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at xxx.yyy.zzz.data.MailReceiver.getMail(MailReceiver.java:109)
    at xxx.yyy.zzz.data.MailReceiver.main(MailReceiver.java:28)
```

When I have `smtp`:

```
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: invalid provider
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:570)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:536)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:515)
    at xxx.yyy.zzz.data.MailReceiver.getMail(MailReceiver.java:108)
    at xxx.yyy.zzz.data.MailReceiver.main(MailReceiver.java:28)
```

and for `imap`, the following:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:613)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at xxx.yyy.zzz.data.MailReceiver.getMail(MailReceiver.java:109)
    at xxx.yyy.zzz.data.MailReceiver.main(MailReceiver.java:28)
```

When I give `imaps` or `pop3s`, I am getting `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` error.

I am not able to figure out what is the error since I am able to send a mail without any problem. I am also sure what I should use in `session.getStore()` either. The tutorial I was following had `pop3`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix the certification path problem.  [This JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#installcert) will help.  Then, use "imaps" or set the "mail.imap.ssl.enable" property to "true".  You also might want to fix these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  And see this [JavaMail FAQ entry about debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug), which may be helpful once you get past these problems.